# Skrollr not working correctly when adding more elements to page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, skrollr

I am using the [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) lbrary to add some parallax to my website, and having an issue when more content is added, the effect does not work.

**It might be better to show you the issue.**

- [Working correctly](http://tinyurl.com/qcfj7ld)
- [Not working when I add more content down the page](http://tinyurl.com/nwnvj6b)

**My code:**

One main issue is the moon.

```
<img class="moon" src="images/moon.svg"
    data-50="top: 460px;" 
    data-200="top: -120px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone else.

I found the library calculates the height of the viewport and adds this to the height of the body.

I just used this to remove it and all is working again:

```
html, body {
    height: auto !important;
}
```